# C++ derived class exception not caught with base class

Tags: c++, exception, gcc4

Exceptions are not being caught in a case where I expect them to be caught.  The code is in 1 function in 1 cpp file which is compiled into a static library by GCC 4.2 and then linked into a Cocoa application.  The code in question is

```
class runtime_error : public exception{
// More code
};


int foo( void ){
    try {
        if( x == 0 ){
            throw std::runtime_error( "x is 0" );
        }
    }
    catch( std::exception & e ){
    // I expect the exception to be caught here
    }
    catch( ... ){
        // But the exception is caught here
    }
}
```

I can modify the code to be

```
int foo( void ){
    try {
        if( x == 0 ){
            throw std::runtime_error( "x is 0" );
        }
    }
    catch( std::runtime_error & e ){
    // exception is now caught here
    }
    catch( … ){
    }
}
```

The second version of the code only solves the problem for runtime_error exceptions and not other exception classes that might be derived from std::exception.  Any idea what is wrong?
Note the first version of the code works fine with Visual Studio.

Thanks,

Barrie

Comment: Is there any reason you're defining your own `runtime_error` class when one already exists?

Comment: The exception should be caught. http://ideone.com/dl0Dm Update your GCC and see if the bug still happens

Comment: The code you've shown us doesn't compile. Please provide a short, self-contained complete example. http://sscce.org

Comment: There is some confusion about the definition of std::runtime_error.  I don't actually define it.  I am simply showing that it is publicly derived from std::exception and hence the exception should be caught.

Comment: I've discovered that a 3rd party library is causing this problem.  If I link the library (but do not call any of it's code) then the problem occurs.  If I do not link the 3rd party library then the problem does not occur.  Any idea's how linking a 3rd party static library could cause this problem?  Thanks

Comment: That is incorrect. You are indeed defining a class and not providing  a forward declaration as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile as written. When I change it as below to add needed includes, variables, etc, it prints "exception" as expected (g++ 4.2 and 4.5). Can you show us the *full real code* that's causing your problem?

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int x = 0;

int foo( void ){
    try {
        if( x == 0 ){
            throw std::runtime_error( "x is 0" );
        }
    }
    catch( std::exception & e ){
        // I expect the exception to be caught here
        std::cout << "exception" << std::endl;
    }
    catch( ... ){
        // But the exception is caught here
        std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is some code which I have just tested which run's and fails in the way originally described: 
 #include "stdafx.h"

 int foo(void)
 {
  try {

   throw std::runtime_error("Error");

   return 0;
  }
  catch (std::exception &e) {
   return 1;
  }
  catch (...) {
   return 1;
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Your class `runtime_error` is a class defined in your code's namespace. I'm not sure why would you use it with `std::` as a scope resolution operator?

Shouldn't the line `throw std::runtime_error( "x is 0" );` be changed to `throw runtime_error( "x is 0" );`?

Comment: There is some confusion about the definition of std::runtime_error.  I don't actually define it.  I am simply showing that it is publicly derived from std::exception and hence the exception should be caught.